# Viewing stored procedures in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access

I'm usually not working with Microsoft products. I have an MS Access 2007 project here, and I know that the MSSQL Server with the Database has some procedures. How can I make them visible? I can just browse trough tables and views...

Thanks and regards,
Jan Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say access project, are using the term that you have a project you're working on, or you do specifically mean you're working with an access data project?  (ADP). The ms access term ADP has an specific meaning that's very important in your context.

In ms access a good number of developers simply use ODBC linked tables to data is sitting on SQL server.  There's also an option in ms access to create what is called a Access Data Project (ADP).  When you choose to create an access data project then any view design services such as the relationships editor, table design etc. looks like you're developing inside of the access desktop client, but in fact behind the scenes access is sending DDL (data definition language) commands to SQL server to make those modifications on the server side object. So, you CAN modify server side objects inside of ms-access. No local tables can exist when you create a ADP.

What this means that the version of access and SQL server have to be more closely matched then if you're not using an access data project.  If you open up the access database and look in the query table, you should see stored procedures appearing in the list.  Access should let you modify them.

So take a look of the file extension, if this is actually an access data project, then the file extension for the access database will be *.adp.

If the file extension is mdb, or accDB, then this is not an access data project, but is a traditional access database in which linked tables to SQL server are being used. This this case of non ADP, then the views and tables you link to will only appear in the tables table. Furthermore ANY design changes you make will be done using the SQL server management tools and NOT the access client. So, changes to tables and views and procedures etc. are NOT made and CAN NOT be made inside of the access client like they can when you're using an access data project.  Despite this limitation, most developers prefer using linked tables as opposed to an access data project because of the loose tie between the version of SQL server. In fact you can use even different database servers in these cases such as Oracle or MySql. The other significant advantage of linked (odbc) tables is that the linked tables allows multiple data sources from local files, server based etc. And, you also can have local tables (ADP does not allow local tables in the client).

So your ability to edit or not edit the server side objects inside of access will be determined by the above scenario IF you are in fact using a ADP or not.

Comment: Dear Albert, Thanks for the detailled answer. I found a tool for managing the SQL Server (I was using this ADP version) that can show me the procedurenames. Unfortunately I found out that they are encrypted, so I will have to contact the developer of the database to get access to the code of these procedures. Thank you anyway!